# What does the notation 【方】 mean in a Chinese dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, notation

In a dictionary entry reading…

> **saggy** *adj.*【方】下垂的；垂曲的；中陷的。

…, what does the notation `【方】` mean?

(Other examples of this notation that I understand include “【美俗】” (American slang), “【解剖】” (anatomy), and “【數學】” (mathematics).)

I’d prefer source material in an answer.

Comment: stands for 方言, dialect, local speech

Comment: source material:袖珍英汉辞典 A Pocket English-Chinese Dictionary 商务印书馆 １９７２ 北京 缩写语 （方）。。。方言

Comment: Usually the dictionary itself would list all such abbreviation used in the beginning of the dictionary.

Comment: http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/js/65B9.htm

Comment: For whatever reason, it didn’t occur to me to check the front of the dictionary; I looked up “方” on Wiktionary instead which says nothing about dialects or topolects. “place; region; locality” is the closest definition listed. It didn’t help that the word “方言” was missing from my vocabulary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 【方】

Is short for 方言.

方言 is defined by [mdbg](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=2&wdqt=%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80) as:

> topolect / dialect

---

Why *saggy* is considered topolectical or dialectical, though, is beyond me.

Comment: This is the correct answer; I should have checked the front of the dictionary per fefe’s comment: it reads “【方】方言 dialect”.

Answer (score -3):

This notation “方” is not short for “方言”.

“方” in “方言、前方” means region.

It's “方正(方方正正)”, which means honesty or integrity.